# What is the difference between "stay home" and "stay home from work"?

Tags: idioms

I'm a native spanish speaker, and I'm trying to understand if there is any semantical difference between the two expressions or they are equivalent.  Automatic translation makes no difference, but I'm interested in any subtle meaning.

Comment: 'We think we'll stay home rather than tour Europe this year.'

Comment: Let's say that I'm calling in sick.  Can say I "I will stay home" or "I will stay home from work" without different meaning?

Comment: If you are calling your workplace to let them know that you are sick and will therefore not be there, then the context makes it reasonably obvious that _I will stay home_ means _I will stay home **from work**_.  They're not likely to think that you're calling to let them know you're going to stay home instead of going to the  ball game.  Much in English is omitted when context makes it obvious.

Comment: 'I am over 12' and 'I am ninety' both apply in certain circumstances. But sometimes, only one should be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Stay home" doesn't explain from where you are staying home.

"Stay home from work" explains that you are staying home, otherwise you would be at work.

Compare it to, "stay home from school."

If you're calling in sick, you shouldn't word it in this way. If I was your employer I would consider it rude for an employee to call and say "I will stay home from work today."

You should say something like "I'm sick, and I won't be able to make it to work today."

Comment: So, saying "I will stay home from work" is the same to say "I will stay home in order to avoid going to work"?

Comment: That will get you fired.  If I am sick, I cannot travel to my job or perform my duties.  I am not avoiding work.

Comment: I don't think it is so much a matter of what it ~means~ but an attitude suggesting, by lack of common custom and courtesy, that the reason is none of the bosses or coworkers business and that you haven't considered them in your decision. You don't necessarily need to be specific(depending on the terms of your contract) but even saying "I need to take a personal day off, I can't come in today"  at least sounds like you have some regrets and that something important is drawing you away. (this is directed at the OP, not Devil07)

Comment: Exactly as @Tom22 or Devil07 said. You don't want to say, "I will stay home from work today", because it doesn't show any regret. You want your employer to know (or at least think) that you have some regret or something pulling you away from your duties. "Hi, boss, I'm sorry, but I'm really sick today and I don't think I can make it to work.". The suggestion in the answer or that Tom22 gave are great options as well.